# Question in the Continuity of a function

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

I have this function:

$$(J''(u)v,w)=(v,w)-(KN_{f'}(Ku)Kv,w)$$ for all $u,v,x\in L^2[0,1]$
such that

$f\in C^1([0,1]\times\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $Ku(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s) u(s)ds$ $K$ is symetric, linear continuousand completly continuous and $$G(t,s)=\begin{cases} s(1-t),~~0\leq s\leq t\leq1\\t(1-s),~~0\leq t\leq s\leq1\end{cases}$$ and $((N_{f'}u)v)(t)=f'_u(t,u(t))v(t)$

So we have that $$(J''(u)v,w)=\int_0^1 v(t)w(t) dt-\int_0^1f'_u(t,Ku(t))Kv(t) Kw(t) dt$$

What i must use to prove that $J''$ is continuous ?

Thank you.